# Selenium Python Copy Text from Input Field in Alert Popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I have a popup window that comes up with some value in which I would like to copy over into my Python program and do something with it.  I am using Selenium to switch to this alert window using the `driver.switch_to.alert` command.  If I were to use `driver.switch_to.alert.text` command, I would get the "Copy this" section instead of the value that is inside the text field.

I have a screenshot of the section that I am referencing.  Please see it for more context.

just simple stuff so far.

```
#switch to alert box
alert = driver.switch_to.alert

#grab text from within the alert box
print(alert.text)
```

however, this only provides the text above the text field area, not the text within the field itself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz3wC.png)

`sendKeys()` won't work since this will send something into the text field and I am looking to take the value that is inside this area instead of sending something new.

Also, this is an alert screen, so using anything with window popups will not work (at least based on what I have looked up).

Does Selenium have a way for us to copy the value that is inside the text field in the alert box?

If not, is there another way to be able to obtain this value for me to save it and use it for the rest of my code?

Edit: Added additional comments regarding the code that I have tried thus far.

Comment: Can you add the `code` what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Akzy
Added code for reference

Comment: After switching to that alert you have to navigate to that field you wanted to get the text. As there is no `HTML` attached for the alert, so I unable to provide the answer.